# Swift: Tableview with section like tableview

Tags: swift, tableview

Hello is it possible to create a single table view but with separate sections? To better understand here is the photo, it is possible to do it in a one tableview or I have to do 2?

[image]

Comment: You can achieve this easily using a single `UITableView`

Comment: In what way? can you show me the way? link?

Comment: You just need to make your cells in such a way that they have 2 labels. One of the left and one on the right.

Comment: I speak mostly of the separation of the two separate paintings by sections, on the picture we see two tableview, and I want to do it in one tableview

Comment: Oh ofcourse! Each of them is a section. You just have to take care in setting up the section header and cell border properly.